# Login with Facebook in grails, error accessing app after login

Tags: grails, facebook-login

I want to provide login with Facebook functionality in my app

I am using spring security core, spring security ui and spring security facebook in my grails app. It is allowing me to login using with facebook and the pop up is disappearing. and then while accessing any part of app with out any request map settings also showing an error showing

```
No such property: roles for class: SecUser
No such property: roles for class: FacebookUser

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: roles for class: com.redkan.FacebookUser
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user registers through Facebook you need to assign the appropriate roles to the `roles` property of the user class and save them. It seems in your case the user is being saved without any roles.

Personally, I prefer not to use the Facebook plugin, because the total amount of code needed to integrate Facebook login using the Facebook API directly is less than 100 lines.

I can share the code I use to add Facebook integration (without using the plugin), if you want it?

Comment: thank you Don its pleasure if u can share it so i can continue the work

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your method `getRoles` of your `FacebookAuthDao` have something like:

```
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> roles = []
    FacebookUser.withTransaction {
        roles = user.roles
    }
    return roles
```

but your `FacebookUser` domain don't have `roles` property.

I guess that you have different name for list of authorities, if that's true, you have to use proper name there

Comment: Thank you Splix  my Facebookuser domain extends secuser domain and i having secrole domain for authorities  and my problem is my user is getting logged in to the facebook but when  i tries to access my app its giving me errors   like this groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: roles for class: com.redkan.FacebookUser
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49)

Comment: so, do your FacebookUser domain have such property?

Comment: @ SPLIX no my facebookUser domain dont have such property

Comment: import com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookUserDomain
import com.xxxxx.SecUser
class FacebookUser extends SecUser implements FacebookUserDomain {

 long uid
    String secret
    String session
    String email

 static constraints = {
  uid unique: true
 }
 
 String getAccessToken(){}
 void setAccessToken(String accessToken){}
 
 long getUid(){
  return uid
  }
 void setUid(long uid){
  this.uid=uid
  }
 
}

Comment: class SecUser {
 transient springSecurityService
 String username
 String password
 boolean enabled
 boolean accountExpired
 boolean accountLocked
 boolean passwordExpired
 String imagename
 static belongsTo=[hospital:Hospital]
 Set<SecRole> getAuthorities() {
  SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecUser(this).collect { it.secRole } as Set
 }

 
}

Comment: Ok, you need something like `user.authorities.collect { new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority) }` instead

Comment: when i do grails run-app  the app is not running and some files r loading Base Directory: D:\workspace\redkanproject
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/social/spring-social-core/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-social-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.pom ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/social/spring-social-core/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-social-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.pom.sha1 ...
Download complete.
 since from 40 minutes

Comment: What if `grails clean && grails run-app`?

Comment: same result  it still tries to download 'spring-social' libarary?

Comment: @ SPLIX  still its doing the same thing am waititng from 40 minutes he still downloading what to do any help

Comment: Can you update your post? It's impossible to understand your situation from comments